# jquery get value of textbox array

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox array in my form. The textbox(s) are dynamically added using javascript function.
The text box are named as below:

```
account[0]_number  account[0]_balance
account[1]_number  account[1]_balance
```

How can I get the values of these textboxes using jquery?

Below is how I tried, but it gives error:

```
if($('#account[' + iteration + ']_balance').val().length==0)
```

Comment: using # is for id references, not names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
var values = $("input[type=text][id^=account][value]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get(); // converts collection to array
```

I'm not sure if you're referring to `name` or `id`, if you are referring to name, then modify the selector to `input[type=text][name^=account][value]`.

Also, `[value]` will only match non-empty elements with a `value` attribute.

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

EDIT this should do it:

```
$('input[type=text][name=account_' + iteration + '_balance][value]').val()
```

Comment: actually I want to access a specific account number or balance at a time. So, converting to array every time i need to access only one account, seems a bit inefficient?
I there a way I can just access a single textbox, if the index number is known?

Comment: @maxxxee - Wow, I had understood something *completely* different. I've updated the answer.

Comment: that worked, can you tell me if it is a dropdown in place of textbox in same scenario, how can i read it?

Comment: @maxxxee - You can use `$('select[name=account_' + iteration + '_balance][value]').val()`

Answer (score 2):

and if you want to iterate through all the textboxes you could

```
$("input[type=text][id^=account][value]").each(function(){
    //put your code here
})
```